# Can I install "Cloud Tools for Eclipse" without installing "Google Cloud SDK"?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, gae-eclipse-plugin

I have used GAE 2 years ago. Now I am setting it up on new machine.

My web application is multi author blog, it will use Datastore for storing data. I want to setup standard environment(and not flexible environment).

1. I have already installed Java 8(Using Java 8 only because it is latest, I can use Java 7 if required).
2. I have also downloaded and setup Eclipse Oxygen(again I can change that if it is useful).
3. I have downloaded and setup 'appengine-java-sdk-1.9.59'.

I wanted to setup App Engine Plugin for Eclipse. Apparently it is deprecated and Cloud Tools for Eclipse is recommended (https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/download).

1. Should I install "Google Cloud SDK"(https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/quickstart) considering the fact that I am developing low volume website and it wont need all that features which SDK might provide?
2. Can I install "Cloud Tools for Eclipse" without installing "Google Cloud SDK"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Google cloud SDKs, including the App Engine SDK, are converging on using the Google Cloud SDK as the delivery mechanism. Yes, you must install the Cloud SDK for use with the Cloud Tools for Eclipse. You will be asked to point to the Cloud SDK directory in Eclipse.